# My action class is being mapped without Struts.xml mappins or java annotations

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I have a JSP login page that would call the login action class. I was using Struts annotations rather than the `struts.xml` to the mapping and everything was working fine. I was randomly trying something new so I removed all the annotations from my action class and my `struts.xml` has no mapping yet somehow my `login.jsp` is able to call my action class. How is it possible that my action class is being called without `Struts.xml` configuration or struts annotations being used?

login.jsp

```xml
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome to Popular Movies</title>

<style type="text/css">
.errors {
    background-color:#FFCCCC;
    border:1px solid #CC0000;
    width:400px;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
.errors li{ 
    list-style: none; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Please Log in</h2>
<div  id="errorMessage" >   
        <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
           <div class="errors" >
               <s:actionerror/>
           </div>
        </s:if>
</div>      
   <s:form action="login" method="post" name="myForm" onSubmit="return preValidate(errorMessage, userName, userPassword)" >
      <s:textfield name="userName" label="Name" size="20" id="userName" />
      <s:password name="password" label="Password" size="20" id="userPassword" />
      <s:hidden name="registration" value="false" />
      <s:submit value="Submit" align="center" />
   </s:form>

   <hr>

   <a href="/PopularMovies/registration.jsp">Sign up free</a> 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js">

</script>
</html>
```

Login.java

```
    package com.esi.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.sans.model.Movie;
import com.sans.model.Movies;
import com.sans.model.user_account;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Login extends ActionSupport {
    private String password;
    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String registration;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String execute() {
        boolean isRegistration = Boolean.parseBoolean(registration);

        System.out.println("Action called from struts.xml");
        try {
            //Setting up Hibernate configuration
            System.out.println("Attempting Database connection...");
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object. " + ex.toString());     
            return INPUT;
        }

        // If Registration flag is set to true then it means user is trying to register
        // else authenticate user
        if(isRegistration) {
            if(this.addUser()) {
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else {
                return INPUT;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(this.authenticateUser(this.getUserName())) {
                return SUCCESS;
            }
            else {
                return INPUT;
            } 
        }
    }

    public boolean addUser() {
        boolean result = false;
        user_account user = new user_account();
        user.setUser_Name(this.getUserName());
        user.setFirstName(this.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(this.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(this.getEmail());
        user.setUser_Password(this.getPassword());

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(user);     
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            result = true;
            addActionMessage("Welcome " + user.getUser_Name());
        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            if(session.getTransaction() != null)
                session.getTransaction().rollback();        
            System.out.println("Error trying to insert user to database.. " + e.getMessage() + "\nStack Trace: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public boolean authenticateUser(String userName) {
        boolean result = false;

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "FROM user_account U WHERE U.User_Name = :userName";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter("userName", userName);
            List results = query.list();

            //If the query result size is 0, then it means user does not exist in database
            if(results.size() != 0) {
                user_account user = (user_account)results.get(0);

                if(this.getUserName().equals(user.getUser_Name()) && this.getPassword().equals(user.getUser_Password())) {
                    addActionMessage("Welcome " + user.getUser_Name());
                    result = true;
                }
                else {
                    addActionError("Invalid User");
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                addActionError("Invalid User");
                result = false;
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();  
        }
        catch(HibernateException e){
            if(session.getTransaction() != null)
                session.getTransaction().rollback();        
            System.out.println("Error trying to insert user to database.. " + e.toString());
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + ex.toString());
        }

        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return result;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getRegistration() {
        return registration;
    }

    public void setRegistration(String registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
    }



}
```

Struts.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <action name="login" class="com.esi.actions.Login">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    </action> 

</struts>
```

Web.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PopularMovies</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

From what I know from struts framework, an action class can only be called if it has been mapped in a struts.xml or using annotations.

Comment: Struts2 first searched the action config for the action, doesn't matter who is provided it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Struts2, the annotations are provided by the Convention Plugin.

The name says it all: ***Convention** over Configuration*.

It means that you *can* configure every aspect of it, but that it will also work by default if you follow certain conventions; this way you have to spend time configuring only those cases that diverge from the standard behaviour.

[Specifically](https://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Codebehindhelloworld):

> **By default, the Convention plugin will find all action classes that
> implement com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action** or whose name ends with the
> word Action in specific packages.
>
> These packages are located by the Convention plugin using a search
> methodology. First the Convention plugin finds packages named struts,
> struts2, action or actions. Any packages that match those names are
> considered the root packages for the Convention plugin. Next, the
> plugin looks at all of the classes in those packages as well as
> sub-packages and determines if the classes implement
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action or if their name ends with Action (i.e.
> FooAction). Here's an example of a few classes that the Convention
> plugin will find:
>
> ```
> Classes 
>
> com.example.actions.MainAction
> com.example.actions.products.Display (implements com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action)
> com.example.struts.company.details.ShowCompanyDetailsAction
> ```

You extend ActionSupport, that implements the Action interface... hence, even if not configured, a `login` action will be found.

---

### EDIT

I forgot to mention that there is a plugin that will help you debugging action / interceptor / result configurations: the [Struts2 Config Browser Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/config-browser-plugin.html). Simply include the JAR in your WAR/EAR, and call

> `http://YOUR_DOMAIN/YOUR_WEBAPP/config-browser/index.action`

You will have a clear sight of every action configured (implicitly through convention or explicitly through configuration) in your webapp.

Remember to **REMOVE THIS PLUGIN before deploying in Production**, or attackers will have (way) more chances to hit you.

Comment: Annotations are used only for convenience to be able to *override* the configuration created by convention.

Comment: Yes: *it will also work by default if you follow certain conventions; this way you have to spend time **configuring only those cases that diverge** from the standard behaviour.*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Struts for long time, I wonder if it is using the class name to do the mapping, Try one of these options to see if that is right or not :

1- Change action="login" to action="login2"

OR

2- Change the class name to Login2

And see if it works or not !!

Comment: Yes you are right it's doing the class name to do the mapping. But now I have updated my struts.xml to map the action to the correct jsp but I keep receiving the following error  "No result defined for action com.esi.actions.Login and result success"

Comment: Can you paste your struts mapping please ? Did you add the success result  like this ? 
 <action name="login" class="com.esi.actions.Login"><result name="SUCCESS">/login.jsp</result> </action>

Comment: There are other tags that you need to add as well {Best practice}  <result name="ERROR">/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>

Comment: I've pasted my struts mapping

Comment: your struts mapping has success all small letters, can you try all capitals ?
 <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>

Comment: That won't make a difference because the "SUCCESS" I'm returning from my action class is inherited constant from the action support class which in turn returns "success" in small caps.